# How can I draw a circle with antialiasing and gaussian line intensity using EmguCV (OpenCV)?

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I need to draw the most perfect circle possible. EmguCV seems to lack an anti-aliasing option.

I'm trying to use SmoothGaussian, but the circle still does not look good/smooth enough.

Also, the circle line intensity should have Gaussian shape (i.e.: brighter in the center).

How can I achieve that?

Here is what I'm doing now:

```
using (Image<Gray, Byte> img = new Image<Gray, byte>(800, 800, new Gray(0)))
{
    PointF center = new PointF(img.Width / 2, img.Height / 2);
    //Center line
    float r = 200.0f;
    CircleF circle = new CircleF(center, r);
    img.Draw(circle, new Gray(255), 1);
    img._SmoothGaussian(7, 7, 3, 3);
}
```

Comment: in c++/python, there's the [CV_AA](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#line) option

Answer (score 4):

If you use Brg, Brga or Gray color you can use that hack:

```
using(var graph = Graphics.FromImage(image.Bitmap))
{
    graph.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    graph.DrawEllipse(new Pen(color.BackColor), x, y, d`i`ameter, diameter);
}
```

`
Edit:
You can also use cvInvoke

```
var center = new Point(x, y);
var color = new Bgr(this.color.BackColor);

CvInvoke.cvCircle(image.Ptr, center, radius, color.MCvScalar, thickness, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.LINE_TYPE.CV_AA, 0);
```

`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that when I have time.